# findIndex javascript problems

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to findIndex of an object in an array containing multiple objects. I've been struggling with this for a while and have simplified it to what you see and still cannot get it. Please let me know what will work so that I can get the "input" object's string from  `matchBetween("string1");`

```
matchBetween("string1");
matchBetween = function (result) {
        let params = [
            { param: "string1", input: "inputstring1"},
            { param: "string2", input: "inputstring2"}
            ];
        console.log(result, params, params.param ); //Output: "string1", (2)[{...}, {...
        let location = params.findIndex (x => Object.is(result, x));
        console.log(location); //outputs -1
        return params[location].input // 'Cannot read property 'input' of undefined'
    };
```

I've attempted multiple things, but I feel like it's an easy fix and I'm just missing it. THank you in advance!

Comment: you're Object.is is comparing each {param, input} object with a string ... so, clearly there's no match ... `x=>x.param == result` instead

Comment: note: `params.param` will always be undefined as that's not how arrays of objects works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.is(result, x)` is wrong.

Run `params.findIndex (x => {console.log(x); return false;});` to see what each x looks like

```
{param: "string1", input: "inputstring1"}
{param: "string2", input: "inputstring2"}
```

So you can use `Object.is(result, x.param)` as Jean mentioned, or `result === x.param`, or simply

```
params.find(x => x.param === result).input
```

Note, you need to handle when result is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample:

```js
matchBetween = function (result) {
    let params = [
        { param: "string1", input: "inputstring1"},
        { param: "string2", input: "inputstring2"}
        ];
    console.log(result, params, params[0].param ); //Output: "string1", (2)[{...}, {...x=>x.param == result
    let location = params.findIndex (function(x) { return Object.is(result, x.param); });
    console.log(location); //outputs -1
    return params[location].input // 'Cannot read property 'input' of undefined'
}; 
console.log(matchBetween("string2"));
```